# Phonegap- Facebook connect. Api calls doesn't fire any callback

Tags: android, facebook, api, cordova

I'm using Phonegap Build.
First of all, I need to say that this error doesn't happen if I try it with an administrator account of the app.
It only happen if a normal user tries to login in my app.

This is my code so far.

```
var facebookPermissions = ['public_profile', 'email', 'user_about_me', 'user_website'];

$(document).on('click', '#btnFacebook', function() { //click
    facebookConnectPlugin.login(facebookPermissions, onFacebookLoginSuccess, onFacebookLoginError)
});

function onFacebookLoginSuccess(userData) {
    alert("userData: " + JSON.stringify(userData));
    facebookConnectPlugin.api('me', facebookPermissions,
        function(result) {
            alert("Result: " + JSON.stringify(result));
        });
};
```

I'm the app's administrator and every work as expected... no trouble at all.
But if another user tries to login, the login works well, but there is no response for the api request.
Only the first alert is displayed

I also tried with this parameters
facebookConnectPlugin.api("/?fields=id,email",facebookPermissions,
facebookConnectPlugin.api("",facebookPermissions,
But nothing changes

I'm kinda lost here, and I dont know what else to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Your App may be in sandbox mode, activate it in the "Settings & Review" section
- `user_website` needs to get reviewed. Without [Login Review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review), it will only work for users with a role in the App.

Comment: Thanks! I tried only with ['public_profile','email'] and it works... It would be nice to have an error of some kind in the logcat to point me in that direction.